# STM32F1/F4: Risks of driving a LED from PC13

Tags: stm32

In the [STM32F411xC/E advanced Arm®-based 32-bit MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00119316.pdf) reference manual on page 71/844, I can read:

> Due to the fact that the switch only sinks a limited amount of current (3 mA), the use of
>   PC13 to PC15 GPIOs in output mode is restricted: the speed has to be limited to 2 MHz with a maximum load of 30 pF and these I/Os must not be used as a current source (e.g. to drive
>   an LED).

You can read the same note in the STM32F103's reference manual.

What can go wrong or what is the risk if I connect a LED to PC13?

It seems "famous" prototyping boards like the [Blue Pill](https://www.techshopbd.com/uploads/product_document/STM32bluepillarduinoguide(1).pdf) and others I have found do have a LED connected to PC13. Is that wrong? Should I try not to use that pin in those boards or is it safe as long as the LED current is less than 3 mA?

Comment: They just keep the current real low with a resistor. A schematic I saw used 1mA, and it pulled LO to sink current to turn the LED on. It did not go HI to source current to the LED.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The datasheet is very strict about this, the pin must not source current.

And Blue Pill is not wrong, the pin sinks current to turn LED on.

Sourcing and sinking in this case just mean direction of current relative to something. IO pin that sources current means current flows out of MCU (it comes from positive supply), and IO pin that sinks current means current flows in to MCU (it goes to ground).

Inside the MCU there is an area called Backup Domain that can be powered via the VBAT battery supply pin even when main supply is turned off, so that real-time clock can keep time and have some SRAM that retains contents during main power loss. Also the IO pins PC13/PC14/PC15 that are related to this Backup Domain must be powered from Backup Domain. There is a switch or supply voltage multiplexer that selects VBAT supply to backup domain when there is no VCC supply available. This supply multiplexer or switch can pass, or in datasheet terms, sink the few microamps that normally passes through it, but can't pass much current or it might break or the voltage drops too much for the backup domain to work properly.

It does not mean there is a constant current sink anywhere. It just means the internal power switch can handle up to 3mA safely in all situations, and backup domain and the power switch itself will stay operational when these three special weak IO pins are used within the limits given.

So, as the switch can provide limited amount of current to Backup Domain, that is why the datasheet says the three IO pins must not be used as a current source. It just means there can be no load that draws current out of the pin. It is acceptable to drive e.g. few CMOS gate inpus, as they draw no DC current and the load is mainly capacitive. Since fast transitions to drive capacitive loads need larger currents than slow transitions, that is why the datasheet says to limit the output pin drive strength to the weakest 2MHz setting, and to limit the capacitive load to a maximum of 30pF.

Comment: The excerpt from the OP starts "Due to the fact that the switch only sinks a limited amount of current..." so the confusion is understandable.  I agree, low-current LEDs should be fine, but it's probably a good idea to use limiting resistors rather than considering it a current source; there's no guarantee it will limit itself to 3mA, and there may well be dissipation issues without an external resistor.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a link or or provide a brief explanation on why is sourcing forbidden or what could go wrong if ignored? I mean, I do not even know what "switch" means in that paragraph in the datasheet. The question is also about understanding what is so special about PC13.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I think "using it as a current source" is just bad wording in this case. I think what they really mean is the pin should not be used to source current, even with a resistor, hence all the schematics sinking current rather than sourcing it to drive LEDs. TBH, I don't even know how you would use a pin as a constant current source to begin with.

Comment: @Peque I wouldn't be too curious about it. It just seems like some designs concessions had to be made for pins that have RTC battery backup functionality. My guess (I'm not a VLSI designer by any stretch) is that it's to minimize leakage and improve power consumption during battery backup.

Comment: I will edit for more details as there seems to be some confusion. Nobody ever said it would be a constant current source.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. :-)

Comment: @Peque I'm not too sure about F1, but on newer STM32s PC13 can be used as an RTC calibration pin or tamper input, both of which need to be in the backup domain.

Answer (score 2):

The limitations are due to the implementation of the "Backup Domain", which  consists both of a battery backed up block of hardware plus related security features which both ensure both its hardware operation and data content integrity. (It includes 80 bytes of battery backed RAM which is zeroed by the system under certain conditions).

The power connection to the rest of the microcontroller is via hardware which is designed to ensure integrity of the "Backup Domain" hardware and memory under out of specification conditions. The power feed is implemented with an eye to intended functionality rather than general user convenience.

A major point of confusion is that the data sheet warning reads

- Due to the fact that the switch only sinks a limited amount of current (3 mA),

But ideally should read something like:

- Due to the fact that the switch only sinks a limited amount of current (3 mA), **but must not be used to source any current at all (0 mA!)**

The Blue Pill designers make this clear in the data sheet that you cite, with specific warnings to this effect.

This is from the 'Blue Pill" page that you cited.
[Bold red lines and text added by me.]

[image]

To comply with this requirement I'd expect an LED driven by PC13 to have Anode to V+ and Cathode to PC13 - + a series resistor designed to allow maybe 1 mA of LED current when PC13 was low.
Which is what is seen here:

[image]

Comment: No, datasheets clearly says PC13 can sink or source 3mA:
"The GPIOs (general-purpose inputs/outputs) can sink or source up to ±8 mA, and sink or
source up to ±20 mA (with a relaxed VOL/VOH) except PC13, PC14 and PC15, which can
sink or source up to ±3 mA" Page 64: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf

Comment: @Radzor The date sheet is inconsistent. || See note 5 on page 33 and table page 60.  || Note 5: "PC13, PC14 and PC15 are supplied through the power switch. Since the switch only sinks a limited amount of current
(3 mA), the use of GPIOs PC13 to PC15 in output mode is limited: the speed should not exceed 2 MHz with a maximum
load of 30 pF and these IOs must not be used as a current source (e.g. to drive a LED)."